# Minecraft /testfor command error questions

Tags: discussion

From my first visit on this site, I have see many, maybe tens of questions that ask about "Why does my /testfor command output an error", but each one is slightly different and asks about the issue of that one person. For example this: [/testfor @p[score_state=1,score_state_min=1] doesn't work!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286862/testfor-pscore-state-1-score-state-min-1-doesnt-work)

It's body:

> /testfor @p[score_state=1,score_state_min=1]
>
> doesn't work! Why?
>
> It returns this:
>
> ```
>   The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format
> ```
>
> How can I fix this?

There have been many, *really* many questions about a simmilar what-wrong-with-this-testfor-command questions (a 2-minute <strike>search</strike> look found me this: [1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286862/testfor-pscore-state-1-score-state-min-1-doesnt-work), [2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191789/minecraft-testfor-problem)) which should be closed as a duplicate, if of course there was one question that would unify all the questions. Every single one of them is one of the problems listed here:

- Why does the /testfor command I have always output an error (not listed below)?
- Why does the /testfor command I have always output the entity UUID is an invalid format?
- Why does the same /testfor command sometimes output the entity UUID is an invalid format instead of found [x] and sometimes not?
- Why does the /testfor command not output anything?

So I decided to put all of these into one single Q&A, so that all the questions can be unified: [Why does testfor sometimes output an error?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286872/why-does-testfor-sometimes-output-an-error)

Can all the questions (that haven't been auto-deleted meanwhile) be closed as a duplicate of this one, that covers *all* the possible errors with /testfor?

Comment: Have you considered making the answer a community wiki so that others can add info if they believe it necessary?

Comment: @angussidney Is it better? Because they can edit anyway, if there is anything needed.

Comment: Generally if an edit comes through review that substantially changes the posts or adds lots more information, it would be rejected because it deviates from the original intent of the author. By marking it as community wiki, you are explicity allowing these sorts of changes. Of course, if you would prefer that people don't make those sorts of changes, feel free to leave it as-is.